# Two words in a string from text file

Tags: c

I'm trying to get two words in a string and I don't know how I can do it. I tried but if in a text file I have 'name Penny Marie' it gives me :name Penny. How can I get Penny Marie in s1? Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    char s[50];
    char s1[20];

    FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt", "rt");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return 0;

    fscanf(fp,"%s %s",s,s1);
    {
        printf("%s\n",s);
        printf("%s",s1);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do it by not using `fscanf` for the second part? Perhaps [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is what you want?

Comment: Also note that the `"t"` flag in your `fopen` call is a Windows Visual C extension. It's not part of standard C. So your code is not portable, and is not plain standard C.

Answer (score 3):

Change the fscanf format, just tell it to not stop reading until new line:

`fscanf(fp,"%s %[^\n]s",s,s1);`

Answer (score 1):

You shall use [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

**Or** you can try to do this :

```
fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s", s0, s, s1);
{
    printf("%s\n",s);
    printf("%s",s1);
}
```

and declare s0 as a void*

Comment: But If the name is Penny Marie Sara ? There îs three words... I think it is more complex. I tried already this.

Comment: Then you just need to format your `file.txt` differently.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers address adjustments to your `fscanf` call specific to your stated need.  (Although `fscanf()` is not generally the best way to do what you are asking.)  Your question is specific about getting 2 words, `Penny` & `Marie`, from a line in a file that contains: `name Penny Marie`.  And as asked in comments, what if the file contains more than 1 line that needs to be parsed, or the name strings contain a variable number of names. Generally, the following functions and techniques are more suitable and are more commonly used to read content from a file and parse its content into strings:

*[fopen() and its arguments.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm)*
*[fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)*
*[strtok()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)* (or [strtok_r()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r))
*[How to determine count of lines in a file](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156477/c-program-to-count-number-of-lines-in-a-file)* (useful for creating an array of strings)
*[How to read lines of file into array of strings](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/143214-reading-array-strings-text-file.html)*.

Deploying these techniques and functions can be adapted in many ways to parse content from files.  To illustrate, a small example using these techniques is implemented below that will handle your stated needs, including multiple lines per file and variable numbers of names in each line.

Given File: `names.txt` in local directory:

> ```
> name Penny Marie
> name Jerry Smith
> name Anthony James
> name William Begoin
> name Billy Jay Smith
> name Jill Garner
> name Cyndi Elm
> name Bill Jones
> name Ella Fitz Bella Jay
> name Jerry
> ```

The following reads a file to characterize its contents in terms of number of lines, and longest line, creates an array of strings then populates each string in the array with names in the file, regardless the number of parts of the name.

```
int main(void)
{
    // get count of lines in file:
    int longest=0, i;
    int count = count_of_lines(".\\names.txt", &longest);

    // create array of strings with information from above
    char names[count][longest+2]; // +2 - newline and NULL
    char temp[longest+2];
    char *tok;

    FILE *fp = fopen(".\\names.txt", "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        for(i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
            if(fgets(temp, longest+2, fp))// read next line
            {
                tok = strtok(temp, " \n"); // throw away "name" and space 
                if(tok)
                {
                    tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");//capture first name of line.
                    if(tok)
                    {
                        strcpy(names[i], tok); // write first name element to string.
                        tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                        while(tok) // continue until all name elements in line are read
                        {   //concatenate remaining name elements
                            strcat(names[i], " ");// add space between name elements
                            strcat(names[i], tok);// next name element
                            tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}


// returns count, and passes back longest
int count_of_lines(char *filename, int *longest)
{
    int count = 0;
    int len=0, lenKeep=0;
    int c;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        c = getc(fp);
        while(c != EOF)
        {
            if(c != '\n') 
            {
                len++;  
            }
            else
            {
                lenKeep = (len < lenKeep) ? lenKeep : len;
                len = 0;
                count++;
            }
            c = getc(fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        *longest = lenKeep;
    }
    return count;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `fscanf` line to `fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s", s, s1, s2)`.

Then you can `printf` your `s1` and `s2` variables to get "Penny" and "Marie".

Comment: And what if there's only one part of the name (like `"Maria"`)? Or three (like `"Maria Sarah Jane"`)?

Comment: And If in the text file I have name Perry marrie /n name Ana Sarah Penny? I should use a while function?

Answer (score 0):

Try the function `fgets`

```
   fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
   if(fp == NULL) {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
   }
   if( fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL ) {
      /* writing content to stdout */
      puts(str);
   }
   fclose(fp);
```

In the above piece of code it will write out the content with the maximum of 60 characters. You can make that part dynamic with `str(len)` if I'm not mistaken.