# fscanf is not working properly once it find a empty field in middle of line

Tags: c, linux, embedded, scanf, fopen

I am trying to read a file each line in loop and store values in a struct. 
When ever fscanf face a empty string it reads everything till end of line and other fields in the line are read as zero. Is there a way to specify fscanf to read the space as a field. 
Below example,

File.db:

```
tick31486081-tick31486081.mtd ,00:00:00:00:01:0e-31486081 , ,0,0,245
tick31486096-tick31486107-video1.ts ,00:00:00:00:01:0e-31486081 , ,1155072,5005312,5005312
tick31486080-tick31486080.mtd ,00:00:00:00:01:0e-31486080 , ,0,0,271
```

After reading the data:

```
tick31486081-tick31486081.mtd ,       00:00:00:00:01:0e-31486081 ,                      **,0,0,245** ,0,0,0
tick31486096-tick31486107-video1.ts ,       00:00:00:00:01:0e-31486081 ,      **,1155072,5005312,5005312** ,0,0,0
tick31486080-tick31486080.mtd ,       00:00:00:00:01:0e-31486080 ,                      **,0,0,271** ,0,0,0
```

is there a way I can handle this not to ignore space to read to a field?

```
FILE *fp = fopen (FILE, "r");
if (fp)
{
    int retval;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (numRead != EOF)
    {
        Node_t *node = calloc (1, sizeof(Node_t));
        if (node)
        {

            numRead = fscanf (fp, "%40s ,%30s ,%33s ,%d,%d,%d\n", 
                    node->name, node->reid, node->hash,
                    &node->startOffset, &node->stopOffset, &node->length);
            printf(" %s ,%s ,%s ,%d,%d,%d", 
                    node->name, node->reid, node->hash,
                    node->startOffset, node->stopOffset, node->length);

        }

    }

    retval = fclose (fp);

}
```

Comment: `fscanf` is very tricky to use here. I suggest reading the whole line with `fgets` and breaking it with `strtok` and after that apply `sscanf` to each token. That will only work if there is a space between each comma for an empty field - otherwise use `strsep`.

Comment: @WeatherVane hash value will be calculated and stored in the node later. fgets and strtok can be an alternative I agree but I am checking if there is no way to use fscanf for this case...

Comment: You could use `%[,\n]` to extract each possibly absent field, but you then still have to apply `sscanf`. Putting the commas and newline in the format string demands an inflexible data format.

Comment: You should check that `numRead` is 6 after the `fscanf` - If not take some appropriate action. Otherwise you will be going around in circles

Comment: I do not mean this to be a shameless plug, but there is an example  of a better way to read content from a file, and parse its contents into strings _[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49032100/645128)_ using `fgets()`, `strtok()`, etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane Did you mean `"%[^,\n]"`?  (^ added)

Comment: Reddy, "I am checking if there is no way to use fscanf for this case".  Yes there is a way, yet @WeatherVane advice to use `fgets()` still should be heeded.

Comment: @chux I guess so, and a solution would need to remove the terminator from the stream too. So back to my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d,%d\n" for format specifiers that will get rid of comma delimiter from first 3 string values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char name[250], name2[250], name3[250];
    int one, two, three;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if(f) {
        int numRead = 0;
        while (numRead != EOF) {
            numRead = fscanf(f, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d,%d\n", name, name2, name3, &one, &two, &three);
            printf("name:%s name2:%s name3:%s one:%d two:%d three:%d\n", name, name2, name3, one, two, three);
            printf("name:%d name2:%d name3:%d\n", (int) strlen(name), (int) strlen(name2), (int) strlen(name3));
        }

        fclose(f);
    }
    else {
        printf("failed to open file\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think you can replace \n in fscanf-format-specifier with a space too.

Good luck!

Comment: 1) `numRead` should be tested before printing, not after. 2) test should be   `numRead == 6` 3) `"%[^,]"` benefits with a width limit like `"%249[^,]"`